# TA says in the solution of this question that Va=v1-((v1-30)/20)*10 , how did he get this?

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image]

TA says in the solution of this question that Va=v1-((v1-30)/20)*10 , how did he get this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider you know the value of \$ V_1 \$. You can write only the essential part of the circuit as,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYAPF8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And analyze it as a voltage divider to get the same result as the TA suggested.